# Как отладить макрос в си?

Tags: linux, c, gdb

https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/queue.h#L72

Вот например макрос с десятком операций вложенных в другие макросы... Как отладить на какой именно операции я попал в сегфолт?

Answer (score 4):

Макроопределения лучше всего дебажить при помощи... Просмотра выхлопа препроцессора! Если используется свободный компилятор `gcc`, то  у него есть замечательный ключик `-E`, позволяющий увидеть код, получившийся в итоге на выходе препроцессора. Достаточно просто запустить:

```
 gcc -E file.c
```

И посмотреть, что же произошло. Не стоит забывать и о флагах, которые может выставлять ваша система сборки/отладки.

А вот отладка сегфолтов - это уже работа отладчика, здесь нужно скорее использовать ключики `-g` и `-ggdb` того же компилятора, чтобы добавить в бинарник отладочную информацию, а потом использовать какой-либо отладчик, вроде `gdb`, который и укажет проблемное место. Но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: это всё понятно, но как совместить это? gdb указывает на строчку в си файле. макрос на стеке вызова никак не раскрывается.

Comment: @eri, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685785/how-to-see-step-by-step-execution-of-each-line-of-a-macro-expansion-using-gdb

Comment: @eri, в подобных сложных случаях я вручную заменяю фрагмент исходного кода  с макросом фрагментом текста, полученным от `gcc -E ...` и смотрю его в `gdb`

Comment: автомата нет ни в какой иде?